# How do I physically restrict access to my machine while still allowing SSH?

Tags: ssh, sleep

I work in a cube farm and want to prevent others from physically accessing my machine while I work from my second location. Is it possible to physically lock out users in the office (for example, through logging out at the original location) while still being able to SSH into my machine at the second location?

thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to leave yourself logged to the system and simply lock the screen. It won't prevent them from rebooting the machine with a power switch if they really want to use it, but it's probably as close as you'll get.

Comment: Leave a broken keyboard and mouse behind in the main machine :) (maybe with coffee stains allover it to make sure no one even think of touching it)